# Bootstrap baseline align a header tag within a column

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, alignment

I have the following bootstrap code:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-1" style="background: red;">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-11 align-baseline" style="background: blue; padding-left: 0;">
    <h6 style="background: green;">some title:</h6>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want the bottom of the green h6 tag to be at the bottom of the blue 11-column div tag

Is this possible? i.e. the green h6 tag should be aligned to the baseline of the blue 11-column div.

Comment: `align-bottom`?

Comment: @temani-afif That doesn't seem to work unfortunately ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the default bottom margin of h6 and replace it with top margin:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-1" style="background: red;">
      1
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-11 " style="background: blue; padding-left: 0;">
      <h6 style="background: green;" class="mb-0 mt-2">some title:</h6>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or align it using flexbox and margin-top auto (still need to remove the bottom margin)

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-1" style="background: red;">
      1
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-11 d-flex" style="background: blue; padding-left: 0;">
      <h6 style="background: green;" class="mb-0 mt-auto w-100">some title:</h6>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks -- which option is better?

Comment: @alex_lewis there is no *better*; both are different ways to achieve your result. Pick one of them and probably one will be more suitable considering your full code (I don't know)

Comment: that's great ... i'll accept shortly. Thanks again for your help.